# Kernel update today didn't need password?

Tags: kernel, updates

I'm here to ask about today's kernel update.

Few days ago (June 15) I updated Ubuntu's kernel to 3.13.0-55.

But strangely, today when I searched for updates, Ubuntu told me to install the same update again. Not just that, but it also didn't asked for the password (something that always happens when installing kernel updates).

Is this something normal?

thank you guys for helping me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you run `sudo apt-get update` for the first time in a day, it will ask for your password.  The `sudo` command by default will store your password in memory for up to 15 minutes.  That is why if you run `sudo apt-get upgrade` shortly after, it will not ask you for a password, until you go and run the commands again later.

From the [Ubuntu Security Team FAQ](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SecurityTeam/FAQ):

> #### Update Manager doesn't prompt for security updates
>
> - Why does `update-manager` no longer prompt for the user's password?
>
>   As of Ubuntu 11.10, `update-manager` no longer prompts for the user's
>     password to apply updates. This was decided to improve usability and
>     to make it easier for users to apply security updates and therefore
>     increase system security. The rationale is as follows:
>
>   - Like in previous releases, by default only people in the admin
>       group are allowed access to perform security updates.
>   - Only updates for already installed software can be applied without a password. Installing additional software still requires
>       people to enter their password.
>   - The password prompt had become an irritant for some people such that they would just press 'Cancel' instead of installing the
>       updates. The password prompt decreased system security for those
>       users.
>   - People that did dutifully apply updates became conditioned to enter
>       their privileged password perhaps daily. When the user is prompted for
>       the password, it should mean something and the frequency of
>       `update-manager` updates meant that some people no longer thought about
>       why they were entering their password. For these users, the password
>       prompt had the potential to reduce security.
>
>   For environments where this change is deemed not appropriate, this
>     functionality can be disabled by the administrator via PolicyKit or by
>     creating users that are not in the admin group (a recommended practice
>     to begin with).

Comment: I know that it would happen with the `sudo apt get update` and `sudo apt-get upgrade`. But I was using the Software Updater (that's why it only asks for the password when it's a kernel update).

Comment: @Nori-chan Updated answer for the Update Manager.

Comment: Thank you for the update. But the Software Updater still asks for every kernel update. And only today, it didn't asked for a password. Maybe it wasn't an kernel upgrade? But yes an update for the kernel that was released 4 days ago (since it's a update for an already existing program, it didn't asked for a password). What do you think it is?

Comment: @Nori-chan mine doesn't always ask untill it needs to have a system restart after the update.  The update from a few days ago didn't need a restart, but today's did.  In fact, I need to restart my host now, as I just ran the updates.  :)

Comment: Strangely, here it asked both times to restart, but it only asked for the password the first time...

Comment: Sorry for the double post. But i just thought: maybe it was just a one-time bug? I even tested to install a program from the software center and it asked for a password.

Comment: @Nori-chan I don't think it is a bug.  I have seen the same thing with the `Software Updater` not asking for passwords, except for certain times.  The `Software Center` has always asked me for passwords, as it is based on what `apt-get` and `aptitude` do where they need elevated permissions to install software.

Comment: I know that the `Software Updater` only asks sometimes for the password (only when they need elevated permissions to install something, which is normally kernel updates). But this time, even through it was a kernel update, it didn't asked for any password (I even had to restart the computer to finish the installation). Are you sure it wasn't a bug? At least, the logs looks normal.

Comment: @Nori-chan I have seen that too.  Most of the time, I have seen it do two different parts of the kernel update.  One does not change the actual kernel itself, but when the main kernel update that alters the kernel itself gets installed, it asks for a password.  In the `Software Updater` sometimes under the Ubuntu Base, you will see updates to the kernel that do not require a password to be installed.  I cannot remember if it is the headers or the image that needs the password in order to be installed.  But I have seen where I get one of them before the other.

Comment: @Nori-chan I checked my dpkg.log, and it looks like the headers come down first. 2015-06-15 18:52:16 status installed linux-headers-3.16.0-41-generic:amd64 and the image-extra which is drivers for that one happened on 2015-06-19 23:48:25 status installed linux-image-extra-3.16.0-41-generic:amd64 and the headers did not the password from what I remember. The image extra did need the password.  Also the linux-image was installed the same time as the extra was, and it forced the reboot.

Comment: I just took a look at the dpkg.log, and I noticed that there's 2 versions of the last kernel update: `3.13.0-55.92` and the `3.13.0-55.94`. I also noticed that both had to install image extra. Since your kernel update is different from mine (I'm using 14.04 LTS), it probably behave different. But still, even through both had image extra,it didn't asked for the password... But, since you said that some kernel updates didn't required the password, I shoudn't be worried about it, right?

Comment: @Nori-chan I wouldn't worry about it at all.  In fact, I like when it prompts for the password, as I know that it will say Restart Required when the update is complete, so that gives me the chance to save my work before I restart the system.

Comment: Ok them, I will still keep an eye on it, if anything strange happens. But anyway, thank you for helping me.

Comment: @Nori-chan You're very welcome!  Have a great day!